# Does a downvote subtract 1 from the reputation of the downvoter?

Tags: support

Yesterday, I downvoted an answer that I thought was wrong, and also added a comment that it was I who downvoted and why. Today, I see that I have a -1 in my reputation because of the downvote. Is it expected that the downvoter's reputation is reduced by 1?

It **could** be justified to prevent frivolous downvoting by making the downvoter pay for the action. I would just like to have that confirmed.

Comment: i think if other users do the same you will get back the subtracted 1 point

Comment: Yes, other users downvoting the same thing makes it more likely for the system to remove the item which will give you back the 1 reputation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

Downvoting an answer will cost you 1 point of reputation.  The poster of the answer you downvoted will lose 2 points.

Downvoting a question will cost you nothing.

The full description of every way to gain or lose reputation is on the main meta site:
[How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/236563)